# Avoid Windows Authentication popup for default page

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, authentication, anonymous

We have a site that uses Windows Authentication to allow access to the webpages. Most if not all pages are written in classic `asp`. I recently added a "public" homepage written in `asp.net` so that users can change their password if they forget it. I tried setting up the homepage as the default in `IIS 6`, and set all the associated files with that homepage to allow anonymous access.

Problem is, we still get the popup for Windows Authentication. If you type in directly: http://www.website.com/default.aspx the page pulls up no problem. But when you try to navigate to simply http://www.website.com, we keep getting the windows authentication prompt.

I tried removing the `global.asa` file and an unused `global.asax` file thinking it was hitting one of these first, but that didn't work. Here are the files that allow anonymous access:

```
default.aspx
/Homepage -- directory with all code files and other public webpages
web.config
/bin -- folder containing the code generated by VS 2010]
```

I feel like something that doesn't allow anonymous access is getting accessed first, but can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have two applications under your Default Website in IIS Manager (IIS 6.0?)  One is your classic asp application, with anonymous authentication, and it uses an application pool with "No Managed Code".  The other is your ASP.NET application, with windows authentication, which uses an application pool set up for .NET 4.0, or something.

Make sure the Default Website is set for anonymous authentication.  Those settings get inherited.

Comment: Not quite. We have a private website that we are trying to give a public homepage (or face). The whole website cannot have anonymous authentication, because we need those pages to be private. We just want everyone to be routed to a publicly available page with some general news before they enter the private webpages.

Comment: Likely then your Default Website is set to Windows auth, and it's demanding authentication before it gets to your Anonymous auth app. You can set up another Website alongsite the Default one to hold the public page, and redirect to your main app as needed. The public website could be, e.g., http://someothername.mainsitename.com.